# To Read XML file in UTF-8 format string using Android

Tags: android

Respected All,
           I have to read XML file, for that I use SAXParser and DefaultHandler using method characters(char[] ch, int start, int length) but it gives output with some extra characters such as [] in place of '#13'. someone told me that if I read that string in UTF-8 format then it will remove that all the extra characters. Is it true that I have to read it in UTF-8 format if yes then how I can read it.
                                                                       Thank You
                                                                     (Vikram Kadam)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use this to parse with the SAXparser :

```
URL url = new URL(urlToParse);
SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
// here we get our SAX parser
SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();
// we fuse it to a XML reader
XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader();
DefaultHandler handlerContact = new DefaultHandler();
// we give it a handler to manage the various events
xr.setContentHandler(handlerContact);
// and finally we open the stream to the url
InputStream oS = url.openStream();
// and parse it
xr.parse(new InputSource(new InputStreamReader(oS, Charset.forName("utf-8"))));
// to retrieve the list of contacts created by the handler
result = handlerContact.getEntries();
// don't forget to close the resource
oS.close();
```

I never had any trouble as long as the initial file you are parsing is properly encoded in UTF-8. Check if it is, because sometimes, when you use default configuration of your computer, default is not UTF-8 but ANSI or ISO-8859-1

Comment: Thank You Sephy
   It gives me Utf-8 format string but there are some html tags such as &lt;b&gt; or <b> and displaying at various places. Is ther any way to remove these tags at once? if yes please help me.

Comment: Yep, for this kind of tags you have to pass your string to Html.fromHtml method. It will return your tags with the proper formatting. Then you can put it in a WebView for instance.
Don't forget to check/vote the answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: Thank You Sephy.
            It Works fine and displaying output without any html tags.
I was searching it for more than three days, but this function works fine.

Comment: Hi Sephy, This is vikram. can u help me to play video files from raw folder using class MediaPlayer.

Comment: I have use                                                 MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(VideoPlayer.this,R.raw.dobeernotdrugs);

Comment: mp.start(). but it not showing any thing on screen...  Thank you.

Comment: hi Vikram, you should simply ask a new question, not over comment this one with another topic ;)